# How to extract the data from spotify web API

Tags: json, rest, spotify

I can't find the JSON object in the http response

I am trying to develop a react app which uses the spotify API to get artist's information. I use `fetch` to generate the GET request

This request should return a JSON with the artist's information.
However, when I print the response to the console, I am unable to find where that data is (in the console I see the header and two "blob" objects). In the developer tools network tab I can see that the response contains indeed a JSON with the data but as I said I am not able to access it through the `response` variable

this is the code I use to generate the request and log the response

```js
var accessToken='here I insert my token from developer.spotify.com';
fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/21E3waRsmPlU7jZsS13rcj', {
            method: 'GET',headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer '+accessToken
            }
        })
            .then((response)=>{
                console.log(response);
            });
```

As I said i get the response without any error, but I need help figuring out where my data lies in that

this is the page of the api https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-artist/

and this is the data I would like to extract from the response

```js
{
  "external_urls": {
    "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/0TnOYISbd1XYRBk9myaseg"
  },
  "followers": {...},
  "genres": ["pop","latin",...],
  "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/0TnOYISbd1XYRBk9myaseg",
  "id": "0TnOYISbd1XYRBk9myaseg",
  "images": [
    {
      "height": 640,
      "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/89863fff0d540475d6fd25e7435138a4e5bd7216",
      "width": 640
    },
    {
      "height": 320,
      "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/38e8be4aed5050c7b0bcf197a86b0e7b5cbb5ddc",
      "width": 320
    },
    {
      "height": 160,
      "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/8573757d9c37eb5178ba8d34a6d6239b055fdf99",
      "width": 160
    }
  ],
  "name": "Pitbull",
  "popularity": 85,
  "type": "artist",
  "uri": "spotify:artist:0TnOYISbd1XYRBk9myaseg"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it: the response object returned by fetch does not contain only the data I am looking for (which are in the response body), but also other information (http status code, response headers ect.)
To get the data I needed, it was necessary to parse the body of the response as JSON.
Luckily, the response object has a handy `.json()` method that does just that, returning a js object I can work with.

So I changed the code to this:

```
fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/21E3waRsmPlU7jZsS13rcj', {
            method: 'GET', headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
            }
        })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.json().then(
                    (data) => { console.log(data) }
                ));
            });
```

Now I get the desired data